# Wordpress pre_get_posts breaks all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I know this should be obvious but my function is making all pages use index.php except the page using archive-project.php and the category pages for that post-type.

```
function change_project_loop( $query ) {

  // Make sure this only fires when we want it too
  if( !is_admin() || is_home() || is_page_template( 'archive-projects.php' )  &&  $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax('projectcat') ) {

// If so, modify the order variables
$query->set('meta_key', 'status' );
$meta_query[] = array(
            array(
           'key' => 'status',
           'value' => 'assigned',
           'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
             ),
             );
$query->set('meta_query',array( $meta_query ) );
}

}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'change_project_loop', 9999);
```

I only want this to run on the home page, the page that uses archive-projects.php and the taxonomy pages for "projectcat".

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect if conditions.

```php
if ( !is_admin() || is_home() || is_page_template( 'archive-projects.php' )  &&  $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax('projectcat') ) {
    // ...
}
```

This means it is not admin page OR is home OR in template **archive-projects.php**
AND `$query->is_main_query()` AND `$query->is_tax('projectcat')` is true.

The `!is_admin()` is always be `true` if you use in theme/template for front pages even `is_home()` and `is_page_template()` is false but one of your condition is met.
And if all `$query` conditions are true then it means this if condition will always work on your front pages.

To fix this, remove `!is_admin()` because it is unnecessary, `is_home()` and `is_page_template()` will work for front pages already.

Also wrap your `OR` condition with bracket to group them.

```php
if( (is_home() || is_page_template( 'archive-projects.php' ))  &&  $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_tax('projectcat') ) {
    // ...
}
```

Now, this means (it must be in home OR using specific template) - one of these conditions must be true.
AND all `$query` conditions must be true.